# How to implement autocomplete feature in my existing chatbot in Microsoft bot framework using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I want to implement autosuggestion feature in my Chatbot based web application.
So if I login and I focus on my chatbot input box then it should suggest me recent item searched by me. and if started typing then it should searched with matched word from my database. Like other search feature of any application.

I searched it in stackoverflow but not getting exact answer.

Please suggest and let me know if you need more detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is no Code providing platform. You have to do research on your own, try it out and present your best not working attempt.

Comment: @Nikolaus Thanks for responding. I am not looking for code. I have implemented it in my application. But I don't want to hit server everytime for showing their recent search. Is any other way?

Comment: You could persist the searchWords in browser(localstorage) or in the cookies.

Comment: @Nikolaus Thanks again. Can I access localstorage saved data from other device if login? Please suggest I have not used localstorage yet.

Comment: No, localstorage is a clientside memory in the browser.